# Chapter name is not corret

Tags: chapters, acronyms

[image]I have this in my pei.tex:

```
\begin{document}




%Capa e pagina de rosto
\include{./tex/capa}

% Agradecimentos
\include{./tex/agradecimentos}

% Pagina do resumo em portugues
\include{./tex/resumo_pt}

% Pagina do resumo em ingles
\include{./tex/resumo_ing}

\pagestyle{plain}

\PEIIdiomaTese

% Indice
\tableofcontents

\LIMPA



%
% Para actualizar o glossario, e' preciso correr o script ./fazindice
% e voltar a gerar o PDF
%
\input{./tex/acronimos}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Siglas}
%\setglossary{glodelim={\noexpand}}
%\setglossary{glsnumformat=ignore}
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\addcontentsline {toc} {chapter} {Siglas}


% Bibliografia

\LIMPA
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\addcontentsline {toc} {chapter} {Bibliografia}

% Indice remissivo
\LIMPA

%\printindex
%\addcontentsline {toc} {chapter} {\'{I}ndice}

\end{document}
```

and this in my acronym.tex

```
\section*{Siglas}

\begin{acronym}[MPC] 

\acro{ACC}{Accelerometer}
\acro{ACID}{Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability}
\acro{API}{Application Programming Interface}
\acro{AWS}{Amazon Web Services}
\acro{BTN}{Button}
\acro{BUZZ}{Buzzer}
...
\end{acronym}
```

But when i compile pdf in siglas chapter appear the last chapter and not the siglas one. Appears the last chapter that is conclusion

Comment: You need to post a small example that shows your problem, no one can debug disconnected fragments of code that inputs files we don't have and uses commands that are not defined in the code shown

Comment: but you have a section with name Siglas but also have `\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Siglas}` so the glossary will make another section of the same name. Is that intended?

Comment: yes i have but i couldn't make index automatic so i found that way to appear the acronym

Comment: well as I say it's impossible to guess what the code fragments you have shown produce unless you make an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i put an image

Comment: No an image is not much help, you need to provide a small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that has something with the wrong chapter name, so people can debug your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the patience. I put more from begin document to end document

Comment: No the point of the example is that people can run it, see the problem, and test answers. A code block that has `\include{some file not provided}` is not an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149070/discussion-between-youngt17-and-david-carlisle).